# Does my PostgreSQL instance support kerberos/gssapi authentication?

Tags: postgresql, installation, authentication, kerberos

I installed it following instructions from digital ocean [how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart):

```sh
% sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

I also did a 'show all' in psql and didn't see anything that suggested it was other than the `krb_server_keyfile = /etc/krb5.keytab` that I configured in postgresql.conf

These are the errors I see in the log:

```
2021-05-07 21:58:49.990 UTC [1434] postgres@postgres LOG:  accepting GSS security context failed
2021-05-07 21:58:49.990 UTC [1434] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Key table entry not found
2021-05-07 21:58:49.990 UTC [1434] postgres@postgres FATAL:  GSSAPI authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-05-07 21:58:49.990 UTC [1434] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 114: "host postgres     postgres           172.31.93.176/24                              gs\
s include_realm=0"
2021-05-07 21:58:49.993 UTC [1435] postgres@postgres LOG:  accepting GSS security context failed
2021-05-07 21:58:49.993 UTC [1435] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Key table entry not found
2021-05-07 21:58:49.993 UTC [1435] postgres@postgres FATAL:  GSSAPI authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-05-07 21:58:49.993 UTC [1435] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 114: "host postgres     postgres           172.31.93.176/24                              gs\
s include_realm=0"
```

Comment: You get this rather unhelpful error when the keytab file does not exist or cannot be read or cannot be parsed.  Did you create a /etc/krb5.keytab and does it work?  You didn't describe doing so, and the tutorial you link to doesn't either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me add some more description of the environment where this problem was observed.

This ***excellent*** series of articles describes setting up kerberos and postgresql

**PostgreSQL GSSAPI Authentication with Kerberos**

1. [Part-1](https://idrawone.github.io/2020/03/11/PostgreSQL-GSSAPI-Authentication-with-Kerberos-part-1/)
2. [Part-2](https://idrawone.github.io/2020/03/12/PostgreSQL-GSSAPI-Authentication-with-Kerberos-part-2/)
3. [Part-3](https://idrawone.github.io/2020/03/15/PostgreSQL-GSSAPI-Authentication-with-Kerberos-part-3/)

If you do this in AWS, you should also setup elastic-ip addresses (so you can stop and start your servers). I also setup rt53 for the host names and have those map to the elastic-ip addresses you setup.

Note: in my case I am using postgresql v13 and after my initial failure, I followed [these instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) on the postgressql for installing postgresql.

You would ***think*** that would be enough. However, if you don't tweak the /etc/hosts file so that you have entries for your servers (as David did in his example, that was on 'in-house' hardware) you get this error:

```
postgres@jl-krb5dev-client:~$ psql -U postgres -d postgres -h
jl-krb5dev-postgres.matlabonlineserver.com psql: error: could not
initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code
may provide more information: Server
krbtgt/COMPUTE-1.AMAZONAWS.COM@MATLABONLINESERVER.COM not found in
Kerberos database FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "52.70.13.95",
user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf
entry for host "52.70.13.95", user "postgres", database "postgres",
SSL off
```

But if you add entries in the /etc/hosts file on your client machine for the kerberos and postgresql machines (using the elastic-ip addresses you setup earlier) everything works fine.

**Note**: this does require that you properly configured postgres with a keytab file.
For v13 of postgresql, I put it in /etc/postgresql/13/main/conf.d/krb5.keytab ***AND*** adjusted the postgresql.conf file (in /etc/postgresql/13/main) so that it has an entry like this: krb_server_keyfile = 'FILE:/etc/postgresql/13/main/conf.d/krb5.keytab

A Big Thanks to @jjanes for getting me on the right path in the comment to my initial question.